# How to returning image from camera intent and placing in google maps api v2 as thumbnail

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I have done more work on this and have read and followed a lot of similar questions (including disecting my own question relating to this) and haven't got much further. My plan is to have the user select a certain point on the map and it opens camera intent and then you take a photo and then that inturn returns a thumbnail on the map at that point (sort off like clicking on the map to place a standard marker)

Now this is my code I have now:

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnMapClickListener{

private GoogleMap googleMap;
static final LatLng xxx1 = new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx);
static final LatLng xxx2 = new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx);
static final LatLng xxx3 = new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx);
static final LatLng xxx4 = new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx);

private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 100;
private static final String imageFileName = null;
private File photo = null;
private ContextWrapper context;
private Intent data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_googlemaps);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();

    if (googleMap!=null){
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(xxx1)
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.campmarker)));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(xxx2)
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.campmarker)));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(xxx3)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.campmarker)));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(xxx4)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.campmarker)));

      }

 CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
         new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx)).zoom(8).build();

 googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

 // adding marker

 googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // false to disable
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false); // true to enable
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); 

   }
  {
}

 @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") @Override
 public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
 Intent getCameraImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File cameraFolder;
    if   (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cameraFolder = new    File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"HickingImages/");
    else
        cameraFolder= context.getFilesDir();
    if(!cameraFolder.exists())
        cameraFolder.mkdirs();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    photo = new File(cameraFolder, "HickingImages/" + imageFileName + ".jpg");
    getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, TAKE_PICTURE);

}    

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, LatLng point)
{
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFileName, options);
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap,10,10);
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
.position(point)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
.fromBitmap(thumbnail));
googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
        }
    }
```

The problem is that everything is working fine, but after the photo is taken it is saved in the folder but doesn't reurn to the map as a thumbnail.

From the log, this is what i get when the camera activity starts:

```
11-24 16:23:55.189: D/AbsListView(9275): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility  4
 11-24 16:23:55.189: D/AbsListView(9275): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Then when returning to the map this is what I get:

```
11-24 16:25:18.049: D/skia(9275): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:50 height:74 bitmap  id is 494 
11-24 16:25:18.059: D/skia(9275): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:50 height:74 bitmap id is 495 
11-24 16:25:18.059: D/skia(9275): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:50 height:74 bitmap id is 496 
11-24 16:25:18.059: D/skia(9275): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:50 height:74 bitmap id is 497 
11-24 16:25:18.069: D/AbsListView(9275): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
11-24 16:25:18.069: D/AbsListView(9275): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-24 16:25:18.079: D/AbsListView(9275): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-24 16:25:18.129: D/skia(9275): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:256 height:256 bitmap id is 498 
11-24 16:25:18.179: D/skia(9275): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:256 height:256 bitmap id is 499 
11-24 16:25:18.209: D/skia(9275): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:256 height:256 bitmap id is 500
```

Its not errors just information I think?
I really don't know if it could be a onResume issue or something else?

I really need some help on this and would greatly appreciate it!!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not extending the onActivityResult method properly, since you have LatLng type as the third parameter, which should be an Intent. You must `@override` the onActivityResult method if you want it to be called when the camera returns. You can read more on `onActivityResult` in the [androidod documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

So your onActivityResult method should look like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
  {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFileName, options);
    Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap,10,10);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
    .position(point)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
    .fromBitmap(thumbnail));
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
  }
}
```

You can "save" the point where the map was tapped along with the `imageFileName` in your activity class, by declaring the `point` variable on the class level. But be careful. Your activity might get killed by the system while the user is taking the picture, so it is best to save the value of those variables in `onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)` and retreive them in the `onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)` or `onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)` methods. Otherwise you might get a `NullPointerException`.

### Edit

```
// Retrieving the value of the point variable when the Activity is recreated
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
  // Your code here
  point = (LatLng) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("point");
}

// Saving the point when the Activity gets killed
onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putParcelable("point", point);
}

// Saving the point in a class level varibale to have access to it after the Camera returned
private LatLng point = null;
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
  // Save the point where the map was clicked
  this.point = point;
  // Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  but now i am getting this error `11-24 17:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(22627): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity{com.test.testparkguide/com.test.testparkguide.Test}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Okay i see now,  basically i am getting the `NullPointerException`.  Could you possibly guide me on how to save the values of those variables?

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you still get the exception, please copy the line which causes the problem.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, LatLng point)` but that method will not be invoked (due to the extra parameter `point'). What will be invoked is the method from the Activity namely`protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode)`.

You have to override that one and find another way to pass your `point` along. Probably within extras.

Comment: Hi thanks!,  i am getting closer i think.  i have declared point as `static final LatLng point = null;` and `LatLng point` to `Intent intent` and `@verride`  and `.position(point)` but when testing the app i get this error `11-24 17:01:05.679: E/AndroidRuntime(17470): Process: com.test.testguide, 
PID: 17470
11-24 17:01:05.679: E/AndroidRuntime(17470): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} 
to activity {com.test.testguide/com.test.testparkguide.Test}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no position in marker options`